# Switch to one-side layout in KOMA-Script scrbook

Tags: koma-script, appendices, double-sided, scrbook

I'm using `scrbook` as document class for my thesis. The two-page layout is just fine in general, but I want the Appendix to be one-sided only.

I read the following post [Switch to one-sided mode in the appendix of a double-sided document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57542/switch-to-one-sided-mode-in-the-appendix-of-a-double-sided-document), but the solution seems a bit too overcomplicated to me.

Is there no native komascript option to switch to one-paged layout within the document? `\KOMAoptions{onepage}` only gives me

```
Package scrkbase Error: unknown KOMA option `onepage' \KOMAoptions{onepage}
```

Alternatively, I might have to compile two different documents and combine them in the end, but this might make referencing harder.

Thanks for your comments!

Christian

Comment: The name of the option is "oneside" not "onepage". Beside this it is rather unclear which features of oneside mode you want to activate.

Comment: Did you try `\KOMAoptions{twoside=false}`?

Comment: @Ulrike AFAIK `oneside` cannot be used as a KOMAoption.

Comment: @karlkoeller: twoside=false indeed did the job. Thanks to both of you for the quick and helpful response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`onepage` is not a valid KOMA option.

If you want to switch to one-sided mode within a double-sided document when using KOMA classes you have to use `twoside=false` (being `twoside` a "simple switch" you can use `no` or `off` as well, instead of `false`), i.e. issue the command

```
\KOMAoptions{twoside=false}
```

just before your appendix.