# How to switch from one sided to two sided document?

Tags: page-breaking, double-sided

I have been writing a thesis that is currently in one sided layout, but I would like to switch everything except for contents, abstract, acknowledgement and dedication into two sided layout. Is it possible? Here is a simple document that uses my current preamble

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report} 
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
 \usepackage{fouriernc}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} 
 \usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={3.5cm,3cm}, vmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm}]{geometry} 
 \usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage{chngcntr} % reset footnote for each chapter
 \usepackage{fancyhdr} % headline
 \usepackage{enumerate}
 \usepackage{wasysym} % symbols
 \usepackage{faktor}%for factor rings 
 \usepackage{ marvosym }
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 %%-------------------footnotes-------------------------------------
 \counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}% reset footnote for each chapter
 \usepackage[hang]{footmisc} %align text of footnotes
 \setlength{\footnotesep}{0.4cm}
 %---------------------note--------------------------------------
 \newtheoremstyle{note}% hnamei 
    {3pt}% hSpace abovei 
    {3pt}% hSpace belowi note
    {}% hBody fonti 
    {}% hIndent amounti1
    {\itshape}% hTheorem head fonti 
    {\spacedlowsmallcaps}%
    {:}% hPunctuation after theorem headi 
    {.5em}% hSpace after theorem headi2
    {}%
  \theoremstyle{note}
 \newtheorem{note}{Definition}
 %------------------------theorem-------------------------------
 \theoremstyle{plain}
 \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter] % reset theorem numbering for each    chapter
 \newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition} % definition numbers are dependent on    theorem numbers
 \newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example}
 \newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
 \newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
 \newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
 \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
 \DeclareMathOperator{\disc}{disc}
 \DeclareMathOperator{\order}{\mathcal{O}_{K}} 
 \DeclareMathOperator{\z}{\mathbf{Z}} 
 \DeclareMathOperator{\q}{\mathbf{Q}} 
 \DeclareMathOperator{\C}{\mathbf{C}}
 \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Span}{\langle}{\rangle}
 \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\bs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
 \DeclareMathOperator{\discr}{disc}
 %--------------------proof-------------------------------------
 \newcommand\prosto{\rule{1ex}{2.6ex}}
 \renewcommand\qedsymbol{\prosto}
 \makeatletter % ''proof''from italic to bold
 \renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
 \pushQED{\qed}%
 \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
 \trivlist
 \item[\hskip\labelsep
    \bfseries
 #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
 }{%
 \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
 }
 \makeatother
 %-------------------headline-------------------------------
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \lhead{\empty} %left headline
 \rhead{\normalfont \small \itshape \rightmark} 
 \cfoot{\empty} 
 \rfoot{\thepage}
 \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
 \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
 \fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} 
 \def\headrulewidth{0pt} 
 \setlength{\headheight}{14pt} 
 %-------------------------------------------------------------
 \usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

 \begin{document}
 \chapter{1}
 \blindtext
 \blindtext
 \chapter{2}
 \blindtext
 \blindtext
 \section{1}
 \blindtext
 \blindtext
 \end{document}
```

Comment: you should switch everything to two-sided (documentclass-option `twoside`) and remove the white pages you don't like afterwards. There are a lot of posts here explaining how to get rid of a blank pages after contents and so on. Using `oneside` only for the beginning would result in different numbering and different side margins (inner less than outer for `twoside`) and therefore should not be done.

Comment: There are no `\tableofcontents` etc. what you want to have... There is also a lot of unneeded packages for the special problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch to one-sided mode in the appendix of a double-sided document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57542/switch-to-one-sided-mode-in-the-appendix-of-a-double-sided-document)

Comment: @ChrisH: That post contains the vice-versa question ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I had exactly the OP's problem -- or at least the desired end result -- and solved it by switching the document to twoside and faking the oneside part as in [David Carlisle's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57559/28808).  Now to remember why it's currently commented out in my thesis!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by switching off the boolean `@twoside` for the front matter.  However, it is not to be recommended.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} 
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={3.5cm,3cm}, vmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm}]{geometry} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{chngcntr} % reset footnote for each chapter
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % headline
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{wasysym} % symbols
\usepackage{faktor}%for factor rings 
\usepackage{ marvosym }
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%%-------------------footnotes-------------------------------------
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}% reset footnote for each chapter
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc} %align text of footnotes
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.4cm}
%---------------------note--------------------------------------
\newtheoremstyle{note}% hnamei 
   {3pt}% hSpace abovei 
   {3pt}% hSpace belowi note
   {}% hBody fonti 
   {}% hIndent amounti1
   {\itshape}% hTheorem head fonti 
   {\spacedlowsmallcaps}%
   {:}% hPunctuation after theorem headi 
   {.5em}% hSpace after theorem headi2
   {}%
 \theoremstyle{note}
\newtheorem{note}{Definition}
%------------------------theorem-------------------------------
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter] % reset theorem numbering for each    chapter
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition} % definition numbers are dependent on    theorem numbers
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\DeclareMathOperator{\disc}{disc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\order}{\mathcal{O}_{K}} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\z}{\mathbf{Z}} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\q}{\mathbf{Q}} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\C}{\mathbf{C}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Span}{\langle}{\rangle}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\bs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclareMathOperator{\discr}{disc}
%--------------------proof-------------------------------------
\newcommand\prosto{\rule{1ex}{2.6ex}}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\prosto}
\makeatletter % ''proof''from italic to bold
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
\pushQED{\qed}%
\normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
\trivlist
\item[\hskip\labelsep
   \bfseries
#1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
%-------------------headline-------------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\empty} %left headline
\rhead{\normalfont \small \itshape \rightmark} 
\cfoot{\empty} 
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} 
\def\headrulewidth{0pt} 
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt} 
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@twosidefalse
\makeatother

\chapter*{Preface}
\blindtext

\tableofcontents

\endgroup

\mainmatter
\chapter{1}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\chapter{2}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\section{1}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Here I have changed the class to `book` that has a two sided scheme, and introduced the subdivisions `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` (references etc. should be in `\backmatter`).  The front matter material is put in a group where `\@twosidefalse` has been issued at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew. I really tried to follow some suggestions given in other posts related to this topic but I was always getting a bunch of errors and no output. Your solution works great. It does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Why is it not recommended?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac It completely f\*cks up a document for print and is outright insane!

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for the reply but I don't think that language is necessary TBH (it is ill-advised in StackExchange in general).

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac I don't recommend it for two reasons: (a) this is muddling with internals, so may have unexpected consequences, and (b) it is subverting the document design, so will not given a consistent appearance.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks for the heads-up; I'll keep that in mind. Alas, it seems like some universities just prefer the *'inconsistent'* alternative just as posted by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem for me was fixed by this workaround

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book} % Start the document with two-sided option     
\usepackage{ifthen}

% Some code

\setboolean{@twoside}{false} % Temporarily move to one-sided mode

% One-sided matter
% ...

\setboolean{@twoside}{true} % Move back to two-sided mode

% General matter
% ...
```

#### Edit:

As mentioned in the comments it is not really advisable as (1) `ifthen` package is [supposedly obsolete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13867/77071) and (2) having both `oneside` and `twoside` alignments in the same file is generally not recommended as it gives a document that is inconsistent and not printer-friendly.

The only reason I had to do this is that this was a constraint imposed by my University to have both one-sided front-matter and two-sided main-matter in the same PDF book; which is exactly what the question specified.

Comment: Are you sure this will work? Where is `\setboolean` defined? Do you have to treat the @ signs in a special way?

Comment: @Johannes_B I had the same problem and It worked for me just now. Using the `\@twosidefalse` as shown in the previous answer just threw me an error stating `You can't use '\spacefactor' in vertical mode.`

Comment: See http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-atvert.html - you need the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` around `\@twosidefalse`.  `\setboolean` is from the `ifthen` package and in effect just wraps the switch command in the necessary pair.  Generally the `ifthen` package is not to be recommend - `etoolbox` is more robust - see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13866/15925