# Switching to mode where content is only on right-side pages in a two-sided KOMA scrbook

Tags: koma-script, double-sided, scrbook

Using KOMA scrbook I would like to typeset a book where the content in some parts only appears on the right-hand pages. The left-side pages should be blank but still affect the page numbering counter. How to achieve this?

Non-solutions for me:

- Switching to one-sided mode (`\KOMAoptions{twoside=false}`) and later back (see [Switch to one-side layout in KOMA-Script scrbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130430/90036)). While I could live with printing some pages separately in single-sided mode, it would break page numbering and the binding correction.
- `\cleardoubleoddemptypage` is no solution since some content gets split between pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution described at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57559/90036 works with `scrbook` as well. In my case I just needed to additionally add a `\clearpage` at the beginning and a `\clearpage\cleardoubleoddemptypage` at the end of the block of pages I wanted to be right-hand sided only.